# Return values in Processes Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am learning about processes and can't understand how receive works
why can't I return values with it

```
defmodule Modifier do
  def loop do
    receive do
      message when is_integer(message) -> message + 1
    end
    loop()
  end
end
```

No matter what I write after -> I get the parameter sent, not the expected modified value.
Expected behaviour:

```
pid = spawn(&Modifier.loop/0)
```

```
send(pid, 1)
```

2

Comment: To return the value, you would need the child process to send something back to the parent process, and the parent process would need to  call`receive`. Not sure what kind of use cases you have in mind, but maybe [`Task`s](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html) might be what you're looking for? Maybe [this intro](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html) can help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), only expressions return values explicitly. Everything else is done through the message passing.

For convenience, below is the amended code which would handle the response message from notifier.

```elixir
defmodule Modifier do
  def loop do
    receive do
      {from, message} when is_pid(from) and is_integer(message) ->
        send(from, message + 1)
        loop()
    end
  end

  def increase(modifier, value) do
    send(modifier, {self(), value})
    receive do
      increased when is_integer(increased) -> increased
    end
  end
end
```

and now use it like:

```elixir
pid = spawn(&Modifier.loop/0)
#⇒ #PID<0.135.0>
Modifier.increase(pid, 1)
#⇒ 2
```

---

In your code, the spawned process had two expressions:

```elixir
# Expr1
receive do
  message when is_integer(message) -> message + 1
end
# Expr2
loop()
```

`Expr1` returned `2` and this returned value, not assigned to any variable, had been immediately discarded by execution of `Expr2`.

Comment: This does work, however I don't really understand why. I understand what is happening, not how it results in me getting the value.
` {caller_pid, message} when is_pid(caller_pid) ->send(caller_pid, message+ 1)`
this code could be used to send back an answer to the process that called this process
and if I write a receive for it 
like `receive do 
           message -> message`
It would give me the modified message. I don't understand how your solution get's around that, and why it needs this back and forth.

Comment: The increase sends it to the loop then the loop sends it to the receive of the increase
and the receive just returns the value 
How come in this case this value gets to the process that started it all
but if I write the receive of the loop to be the same as the increase it doesn't
and, I tried without recursion it's not any different.

Comment: There is no recursion, in the first place. The calculation happens in the _spawned_ process. You want the value in your initial process, which started the _spawned_ one. Hence, the _spawned_ process must send the message, there is no other way for anything to get to its internal state. It sends the message, your initial process receives it, and returns _as a result of the latest expression_ in a call to `increase/2`. The latter returns the value from the function. That’s it.